# Post request with many-to-many relation

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

I want to send a post request to my API that includes relations for example:

```
{
"name": "test",
"description": "test",
"releaseDate": "0001-01-01T00:20:40",
"publisherId": 1
}
```

Where publisherId is the foreign id.
I can get this to work for one-to-many relations but not many-to-many.
This is my model right now:

```
public class Game
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    public int? PublisherId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<int> DeveloperIds { get; set; }
    public ICollection<int> CategoryIds { get; set; }
    public ICollection<int> PlatformIds { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("PublishedGames")]
    [ForeignKey("PublisherId")]
    public virtual Company Publisher { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DeveloperIds")]
    public virtual ICollection<GameCompany> Developers { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryIds")]
    public virtual ICollection<GameCategory> Categories { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PlatformIds")]
    public virtual ICollection<GamePlatform> Platforms { get; set; }
}
```

but I can't add this to the model...

```
    [ForeignKey("DeveloperIds")]
    public virtual ICollection<GameCompany> Developers { get; set; }
```

The error is pretty self-explanatory but I don't know whether those suggestions are the right thing to do.

> System.InvalidOperationException
> HResult=0x80131509
> Message=The property 'Game.DeveloperIds' could not be mapped, because it is of type 'ICollection' which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type. Either explicitly map this property, or ignore it using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

I've also tried other types like *IEnumerable*, *IList*, *List* and an array but without success.
How do I work around this? Thanks in advance

I can't use .NET 5 either because google app engine doesn't support that.

Edit:
GameCompany class:

```
public class GameCompany
{
    public int GameId { get; set; }
    public Game Game { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

GameController:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<GameRepresentation> CreateGame([FromBody] Game newGame)
    {

        context.Games.Add(newGame);
        context.SaveChanges();

        var game = context.Games
              .Include("Platforms")
              .Include("Categories")
              .Include("Developers")
              .Include("Publisher")
              .Single(br => br.Id == newGame.Id);

        List<int> PlatformIds = new List<int>();
        foreach (GamePlatform platform in game.Platforms)
        {
            PlatformIds.Add(platform.PlatformId);
        }
        List<int> CategoryIds = new List<int>();
        foreach (GameCategory category in game.Categories)
        {
            CategoryIds.Add(category.CategoryId);
        }
        List<int> DeveloperIds = new List<int>();
        foreach (GameCompany developer in game.Developers)
        {
            DeveloperIds.Add(developer.CompanyId);
        }

        var toReturn = new GameRepresentation
        {
            Id = game.Id,
            Name = game.Name,
            Description = game.Description,
            ReleaseDate = game.ReleaseDate,

            PublisherId = game.Publisher?.Id,
            PublisherName = game.Publisher?.Name,

            PlatformIds = PlatformIds,
            CategoryIds = CategoryIds,
            DeveloperIds = DeveloperIds
        };
        return Created("" ,toReturn);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show GameCompany class pls?

Comment: @Serge added to original post

Comment: What version of Net are you using?

Comment: using .NET Core 3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to change your model

```
public class Game
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    
    // public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }
     [InverseProperty(nameof(GameCompany.Game))]
    public virtual ICollection<GameCompany> Developers { get; set; }
  
}
public class Company
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
  
     //public virtual ICollection<Game> Games { get; set; }
  [InverseProperty(nameof(GameCompany.Company))]
    public virtual ICollection<GameCompany> Developers { get; set; }
  
}

public GameCompany
{
[Key]
 public int Id { get; set; }
[ForeignKey(nameof(CompanyId))]
[InverseProperty("Developers")]
public int GameId { get; set; }
 public virtual Game Game{ get; set; }
 
 public int CompanyId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey(nameof(CompanyId))]
[InverseProperty(nameof(Company.Developers))]
public virtual Company Publisher{ get; set; }
}
```

and db context

```
modelBuilder.Entity<GameCompany>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasOne(d => d.Game)
                    .WithMany(p => p.GameCompany)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.GameId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
                  

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Company)
                    .WithMany(p => p.GameCompany)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.CompanyId);
                   
            });
```

Update

Since you posted new updates and corrected code according to my answer , fix these by adding [NotMapped]

```
[NotMapped]
public ICollection<int> DeveloperIds { get; set; }
[NotMapped]
public ICollection<int> CategoryIds { get; set; }
[NotMapped]
 public ICollection<int> PlatformIds { get; set; }
```

Comment: Then how do I handle the post request in my controller for example, what type do I use in this part: `CreateGame([FromBody] Game newGame)`?

Comment: Pls post the whole action

Comment: I cant see any Platforms and  Categories in your game class

Comment: And you have to update to Net5, otherwise  the select game code will be  much more compicated.

Comment: I update the game class but i can't got to .NET 5 because I have to deploy it to the google cloud app engine which doesn't support .NET 5

Comment: Now  your create action should be working already. you only have to remove [Required] from Ids.  Do you have any problems?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this is the ideal solution but I got it working by manually creating the joining entity 'GameCompany' (same thing for the other entities)

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<GameRepresentation> CreateGame([FromBody] Game gameFromBody)
    {
        context.Games.Add(gameFromBody);
        context.SaveChanges();
        var publisher = context.Companies.Single(b => b.Id == gameFromBody.PublisherId);
        ICollection<GameCompany> developers = new List<GameCompany>();
        foreach (var developerId in gameFromBody.DeveloperIds)
        {
            var Company = context.Companies.Single(b => b.Id == developerId);
            developers.Add(new GameCompany()
            {
                GameId = gameFromBody.Id,
                Game = gameFromBody,
                CompanyId = developerId,
                Company = context.Companies.Single(b => b.Id == developerId)
            });
        }
        ICollection<GamePlatform> platforms = new List<GamePlatform>();
        foreach (var platformId in gameFromBody.PlatformIds)
        {
            platforms.Add(new GamePlatform()
            {
                GameId = gameFromBody.Id,
                Game = gameFromBody,
                PlatformId = platformId,
                Platform = context.Platforms.Single(b => b.Id == platformId)
            });
        }
        ICollection<GameCategory> categories = new List<GameCategory>();
        foreach (var categoryId in gameFromBody.CategoryIds)
        {
            categories.Add(new GameCategory()
            {
                GameId = gameFromBody.Id,
                Game = gameFromBody,
                CategoryId = categoryId,
                Category = context.Categories.Single(b => b.Id == categoryId)
            });
        }

        gameFromBody.Categories = categories;
        gameFromBody.Developers = developers;
        gameFromBody.Platforms = platforms;
        context.SaveChanges();

        return Created("", gameFromBody);
    }
```

Models:

```
public class Game
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    public int? PublisherId { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<int> DeveloperIds { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<int> CategoryIds { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<int> PlatformIds { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("PublishedGames")]
    [ForeignKey("PublisherId")]
    public virtual Company Publisher { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GameCompany> Developers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GameCategory> Categories { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GamePlatform> Platforms { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Game> PublishedGames { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GameCompany> DevelopedGames { get; set; }
}

public class GameCompany
{
    public int GameId { get; set; }
    public virtual Game Game { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```